# Wordpress: disqus won't load on new posts

Tags: wordpress, comments, disqus

I have a weird problem with disqus.

I transfered my site www.pcsteps.gr from joomla to wordpress a few days ago.

On the 1400+ transfered articles, such as this http://goo.gl/BwlnmX, the comments show fine on the bottom of the page. This was the last post I made on Joomla.

However, on each and every article I posted after that, there is no comments section whatsoever (eg here http://goo.gl/1uyDOl, the very next post, first on Wordpress) there is no comments section whatsoever.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Disqus, and also reset its's settings, but nothing seems to be working.

I send a message to disqus support, but they still haven' answered 8 days later.

Any help is appreciated, this is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any Disqus JS code in your page source that can load comments form. Could you show us your single.php and comments.php files?

Comment: This is the single.php of my theme http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=RVQVWTVv

and this is my comments.php http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yW4VkG4B